# JavaFX - Pane Size Property-Binding

Tags: java, javafx

I want to get a Pane inside another Pane and adjust the size of the inner-pane in relation to the outer Pane.
To do that, I wanted to create a Pane and bind its width and height properties to the outer-pane, but I can't find any pane which supports that.

I know that could be quite difficult because Region doesn't support that, but is there at least a way I could set a maximum size to a Group, so that bigger child-elements are just cut-off ?

I hope anyone could help me out with this problem.

Thank you already!

Lukas

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after.

Comment: Couldn't find a pane which meets my needs, but I helped myself out with a Pane inside an AnchorPane. The AnchorPane resizes the inner-pane on it's own. cu Lukas

Comment: It's unclear what *"adjust size of inner pane in relation to outer pane"* exactly means. There are some panes that could fit this description, but we cannot be sure, if they'd meet the requirements with the description you currently provide.

Comment: I want a Pane, which width/height properties I can bind to another pane's width and height properties so that these two panes are always in relation to each other. I also want my own ration, that's why I can't use a standard pane except those who offer me to locate my pane on my own, like a "Pane" or a "Group".